# String Interpolation in JSX(React)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, string, jsx

I'm trying to replace concatenation with interpolation in JSX.Is this the correct approach

Can i place the `$` outside the bracket common for all? All these are constants or variables.

`${x.val1}${minus}${val2}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's inside the JSX markup, then

```
{`${x.val1}${minus}${val2}`}
```

is the correct syntax.